# How to get the square of a value in SCSS mathematically?

Tags: css, sass

Sass doesn't have a power function. So how could I do a power operation like this?

```
.className {
  padding: 2^2; // Should equal 4
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with reading the documentation when you are unclear on how operators work in a language?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/power-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make a function for it something like:

```
@function power($number, $power) {
    $exponent: 1;

    @if $power > 0 {
        @for $i from 1 through $power {
            $exponent: $exponent * $number;
        }
    } @else if $power < 0 {
        @for $i from 1 through $power {
            $exponent: $exponent / $number;
        }
    }

    @return $exponent;
}
```

The credit should go to this guy who made this: https://www.bhalash.com/archives/13544805657